# MPMoviePlayerControler fullscreen problem if opened on PresentModalViewController in iPad

Tags: ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a problem opening a MPMoviePlayerController in fullscreen mode starting from a presentModalViewController.

I open a presentModalViewController

```
//Create controller
mDetailFilmController = [[DetailFilmController alloc]
                                    initWithNibName:@"DetailFilmController" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                         initWithRootViewController:mDetailFilmController];

//Set modal style
navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
navController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

//presentModalViewController
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];


//Dimension
navController.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 700, 700);
```

in DetailFilmController there's a MPMoviePlayerController and this is the code for play button:

```
self.mPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];

//set url
self.mPlayer.contentURL = btn.linked_url;

//set dimension
self.mPlayer.view.frame = self.view.frame;

//AddSubView
[self.mViewForMovie addSubview:mPlayer.view];

//Notify
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]  addObserver:self selector:@selector(_moviePlayerDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:mPlayer];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]  addObserver:self selector:@selector(_moviePlayerDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:mPlayer];

//fullscreen
[self.mPlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];

//start play
[self.mPlayer play];
```

the problem occured when i try to click done button, this doesn't work.

Only in the area of the presentModalViewController below is possible to intercept the click.

What did I do wrong?

thanks for help

Don

Comment: I have the same problem as you. Did you find a fix for this?

Comment: hi, i try to remember.. the modal view was the problem, i dismiss the modal view before open the movieplayer.
When the movieplayer finish i re-open the modal view.
if you need code i will search for it